# different between (-(a.b)) and ((-a).b)

Tags: differential-operators

One of our teachers said that there is just one example that there is different between $(-(a\cdot b))$ and $((-a)\cdot b)$. He said by using "twice complement," you can find one.

I am trying to find this example. Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What precisely is "*"? Because in a field, $-(a\cdot b)=(-a)\cdot b$.

Comment: @Meelo Thanks, I edited it

Comment: What do you mean by saying "twice complement"? Thanks

Comment: @JrAntalan it is a logic that you can use in binary calculation.

Comment: I see thanks @user215527

Comment: He has "differential operator" tag.  So maybe this "difference" is for such operators, not for elements of a field.

Comment: You are the one who used tag "differential-operators", so I guess only you know what you meant by it.

Answer (score 0):

I noted one difference between the two in the realm of abstract algebra.

$-(a\cdot b)$ is the additive inverse of$a\cdot b$

While the other is the product of the additive inverse of $a$ to $b$.

That's there difference in context.But nontheless they are equal by a theorem in abstract algebra.

Comment: But you know, I want an example for a. I should find an example.

Comment: Will post an answer if I find it :-).

Comment: Thanks, I really need it. ;)